# [Jenkins][Pipeline] Not able to upload APK to hockeyapp

Tags: android, jenkins-pipeline, apk, hockeyapp

I am planning to upload an APK to hockey app through Jenkins Pipeline. My upload is failing.

Can anyone help me on this issue

Trying to upload android APK with an error.

```
def DEV_APK_PATH="APP/build/outputs/apk/mobileDevelopment/release/*.apk"
def DEV_MAPPING="APP/build/outputs/mapping/mobileDevelopment/release/mapping.txt"

pipeline {
    agent { label 'ABC' }
    stages {
        stage('Upload To HockeyApp') {
            when {
                expression { return params.UPLOAD_HOCKEYAPP }
            }

            steps {
                // Build Android
                archiveArtifacts DEV_APK_PATH
                hockeyApp applications: [
                                  [
                                    apiToken: 'HOCKEY_APP_TOKEN',
                                    downloadAllowed: true,
                                    filePath: DEV_APK_PATH,
                                    dsymPath: DEV_MAPPING
                                    releaseNotesMethod: changelog('true'),
                                    uploadMethod: versionCreation('app-id')
                                  ]
                                ], debugMode: false, failGracefully: false
            }
        }
    } // stages
} // pipeline
```

Error Log:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:enter code here WorkflowScript: 44: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 44, column 39.
                       hockeyApp applications: [
                                             ^
1 error
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: maybe adding a comma after `dsymPath: DEV_MAPPING`?

Comment: does it help to solve the issue?

Comment: Solved. Thank you. but I am unable to upload it to Hockey app still. I am getting this error."java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'hockeyApp' found among steps ["